# Adobe Photoshop can't use Liquify tool & Face tool

Tags: adobe, photoshop

When i've trying to use Face Tool in Liquify tool, i get an error:
The Face Tool requires hardware acceleration. Check the Perfomance Preferences and verify that "Use Graphics Processor" is enabled.

But in Perfomance settings, all these settings are On, and GPU Compatibility chek says that "Your graphics processor is compatible"

Adobe Photoshop Version: 24.1.1 20230112.r.238 4bbfa7a  x64

[image]

[image]

I've tried to update my graphics driver, so now it is latest version of nvidia driver (528.49 from 02/08/2023)

Comment: You'd be better off asking this [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) as your question is considered off topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the nvidia 527.56 driver, maybe it will help you, I have no problems with Liquify.

Studied this problem on the adobe forums.